# SQL Server SSIS no current row

Tags: sql-server, ssis, buffer, row, bids

My current package consists of an Excel Source, a Script component, and an OLE DB destination. All I am trying to accomplish is to transform one of my columns. For this specific column I want a substring of the column. However, I keep getting the following error message:

```
 There is no current row in the buffer. A row may need to be added using the AddRow method.
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception e)
```

What does that mean? Why would I need to Add Rows when all I am doing is transforming data? Am I missing the big picture about SSIS?

Here is my code in the script:

```
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        OutBuffer.labortypewbs = Row.CopyofLevel2ProjectSegment.Substring(Row.CopyofLevel2ProjectSegment.Length - 2, 2);
    }
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you post the code which you have written in script component

Comment: @praveen I would be happy to.

Comment: You need to add the row before you assign the values to the output column  .Kindly add the statement OutBuffer.AddRow() before the statement outbuffer.labortypewbs=.........

Comment: from what you have written, I think you could very well use a derived column transformation and use the SUBSTRING function that comes along with SSIS. Let us know if you would like to use that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a derived column rather than a script component.  You can add a column that is a substring of an existing column trivially with that component, and you don't have to write any code or learn the intricacies of script component programming.  I would only use a script component if:

1. I had a case where there was no existing component to do the transformation I wanted.
2. The component I needed to use was not fast enough or accurate enough (with proof) to use.

I have had a few edge cases where a script component was the best solution, but they are few and far between, and a substring is not one of those cases.

Answer (score 4):

While you can use a derived column to accomplish this as William has indicated, it's worth mentioning the solution to the actual problem experienced.

Before you can set values of your output columns, you first have to add a new row. Your code should be:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    OutBuffer.AddRow();
    OutBuffer.labortypewbs = Row.CopyofLevel2ProjectSegment.Substring(Row.CopyofLevel2ProjectSegment.Length - 2, 2);
}
```